# SendInput MOUSEEVENT_MOVE causes screen flickering

Tags: c++, winapi

So I am trying to write a program in c++, which moves mouse cursor as if user moved mouse.
I have something a piece of code, which looks like this:

```
std::atomic<bool> exit_condition = false;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> ud(-20, 20);
void move_mouse() {
    while (!exit_condition) {
        INPUT input;
        input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        input.mi.mouseData = 0;
        input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
        input.mi.dx = ud(gen);
        input.mi.dy = ud(gen);
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    }
}
```

The thing is, when the program reaches this loop, screen starts flickering.

I have second display connected to my laptop through HDMI cable and it gets completely turned off while laptop's display turns on/off every (what I believe) few cycles.

Mouse moves, tho. So the program does what I want, kind of...

Does anyone knows what is going on there? Can you, please, help me to understand the underlying problem?

One more thing, the following code has the same effect:

```
void move_mouse() {
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.mouseData = 0;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    while (!exit_condition) {
        input.mi.dx = ud(gen);
        input.mi.dy = ud(gen);
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    }
}
```

I use MS Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 machine to build my "solution". Switching from x32 to x64 build config doesn't work.
_MSC_VER is 784. _MSC_FULL_VER is b78391c. I don't know if it is relevant.

// EDIT:
I fixed flickering by using `mouse_event`:
`mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, ud(gen), ud(gen), 0, NULL);`

But the question remains: why?
When I add `input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;` and use `SendInput` flickering still occurs.
What else am I missing?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `SetCursorPos()` instead of `SendInput()`? At the very least, you should always zero out Win32 API structures before populating them. You are not filling in the `time` and `dwExtraInfo` fields of `input.mi`, so they have *indeterminate* values.

Comment: ```SetCursorPos``` doesn't do what I want. As for time, you're right, I forgot about it. But why such drastic side effects though?

Comment: Windows uses the timestamp of events in the input queue to decide when it's time to turn the screensaver or low power mode on and off...

Comment: "*SetCursorPos doesn't do what I want*" - which is what exactly? There is little difference between `SetCursorPos()` and `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, ud(gen), ud(gen), 0, NULL)` other than handling of relative vs absolute coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jonathan Potter said that, windows uses the timestamp of events in the input queue to decide when it's time to turn the screensaver or low power mode on and off.

So the problem lies in the time stamp. The solution is to use the system's own time stamp.

> The time stamp for the event, in milliseconds. If this parameter is 0,
>   the system will provide its own time stamp.

You can use `memset` to initialize `SendInput`.

```
memset(&input, 0, sizeof(input));
```

Or

Add `input.mi.time = 0;`